# Jdbc Connection Pooling - using multiple schema known at runtime only

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, database-schema, spring-jdbc

I am working on an engine that is doing the following:

1. gets data provider info from DB (that tells me to what database & schema details to connect to get my data)
2. use that info to connect to the database and get my data, that later I use to build some XML content.

The standard setup to handle and isolate database connection management would be to create a DataSource bean (I'm using Spring to wire my components) and inject that in my ProviderConfigDao (loads connection config) and ContentDao (loads data using connection details loaded previously). This would nicely isolate the handling of the connections from the actual code, thus the DAO classes not needing to know how and when a connection is created/opened/closed etc.

This setup doesn't work unfortunately, as when I create my connection, I need to be able to specify the database schema. I don't know all the different schemas from the beginning, so I can't create a set of DataSource objects to cover all of them, thus the DataSource object must be created at runtime and it's creation hidden from the users.

The only solution I can think of is:

1. Have another class/interface (DataSourceProvider) having one method:

   ```
   //Gets the connection URL as parameter (which includes the schema name).
   DataSource getDataSource(String url);
   ```
2. Add a bean in Spring config to provide a custom implementation for it that manages creation of DataSource objects for each schema.
3. Inject that object to my DAO classes instead of the DataSource object.

It's not a bad solution, but I was wondering if there is maybe support for something like this already in some open source package ... I'd rather use something already done and tested then reinvent the wheel.

Cheers,
Stef.

Comment: Have you implemented your old solution for your project or have you discovered something better?

Comment: I didn't find anything better ...

Answer (score 0):

there's a JDBC Utils to get all the metada from a database `org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils`
parameters:

1. DataSource
2. Implementation of `org.springframework.jdbc.support.DatabaseMetaDataCallback`